# bring values from function into another php file

Tags: php, function, dompdf

I am trying to clean up my file structure for managing the sending of an email with a dompdf attachment.

However i cant quite work out how to include the html file separately and still retain the values. Im trying this with a function but it does not work.

I have a file containing this ( pdf.php )

```
<?php 

function template_PDF($html) {

$html  ='<doctype>...';
$html .='<title>'.$pagetitle.'</title>';
$html .='<p>More stuff</p>';

} 

?>
```

I have another file ( processor.php )

```
include('pdf.php');

$pagetitle = $_POST['title']; // this is only an example

$ticketno = 'noyb'; // this is only an example

$html = template_PDF($html);

require_once("/home/clientname/public_html/framework/pdf/dompdf.php");

$dompdf=new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->set_paper('a4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$pdf=$dompdf->output();

file_put_contents("/home/clientname/docs/REF".$ticketno.".pdf", $pdf);
```

Basically just trying to clean things up. Im not after some elaborate solution. if anyone can help shed light on how to bring that function my file and still retain the values. The function needs to spit out values from within the file its being included in basically.

Thanks in advance
Jonny

Comment: Absolutely unclear, what are you trying to do? What goes wrong? And one more notice - your function `template_PDF` doesn't return anything. Use `return` statement in it.

Comment: hi @u_mulder - im trying to get a html snippet that will eb used to create a pdf form using dompdf. It works if i just add it into the processor.php file but im trying to work out how i can keep it outside. It just makes it easier format my code. As for my understanding - its limited. Thats why i asked. Im really just after a simple example. Of how to write a function that can contain values from the page it will be included in.

Comment: Also my question is pretty obvious. Im trying to LEARN.. how to wrap some html with values in it - inside a function and then include that function in another file. How clear do you want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of bloating your PHP with HTML inside a `variable` you should create a HTML file with placeholders :

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>{title}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {content}
</body>
</html>
```

The placeholders in this template are `{title}`and `{content}` 
Now what u do is access the template file with :

```
$html = file_get_contents('location/template.html');
```

The next step is to replace your placeholders, this can be done this way :

```
$needles = array(
    '{title}',
    '{content}',
);
$replaces = array(
    $_POST['txt_title'],/* don't forget to sanitize user input*/
    $_POST['txt_content'],
);
$html = str_replace($needles, $replaces, $html);
```

And then pass the `$html` to DOMPDF

Comment: Oh wow, thats what they call templating right. Like smarty and moustache? I like it. Its never been explained more simply to me. Thanks. I will try this when its not midnight and get back to you. I think this will work very well and allow me to use it as part of many templating thingies i have. Thanks heaps @DarkBee

Comment: Yes, this is the most basic templating there is. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the template_PDF function whatever data it needs.  From your example, that is only $pagetitle.  You also need the function to return the result back to you.  So now your function should become:

```
function template_PDF($pagetitle) {

$html  ='<doctype>...';
$html .='<title>'.$pagetitle.'</title>';
$html .='<p>More stuff</p>';
return $html
}
```

Then you will call the function as:

```
$html = template_PDF($pagetitle);
```

You give the function the page title that you retrieved from the $_POST (and any other relevant data you want to add), and the function returns the completed html.

Comment: thankyou. But what if i have more than just pagetitle - i have lots of values.

Comment: I'll usually include up to 3-4 parameters to a function.  If you need to pass more than that you should put them in an array first and simply pass the array.  Then the receiving function can check for the array indexes it expects.